# map loading error while using callbacks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, callback

I'm working on a RPG using melonJS, HTML5, CSS3, and PHP.

When I load the game and login, it is supposed to read my stats from a database (level, experience, etc).

When I load the game for the first time, I get a **blank screen:**

[image]

**With error:**

```
Uncaught melonJS: level mymap2<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-si...<omitted>...nd     
at   melonJS-0.9.11-min.js:13
```

The error is at `melonJS-0.9.11-min.js:13`, so I'm not sure where to debug there.

---

**If I refresh, it loads just fine:**

[image]

This leads me to believe there is a caching error, or maybe the callback I'm using to load the current level is returning the level name after the rest of the markup has loaded.

To login, I'm using a typical session, then setting header to relocate to the game if they successfully log in.

**On document ready, I send a $.get to a PHP file to load the map:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.get("php/CRUD.php", {"_functionToRun" : "getLevel"},
    function (returned_data) {
        game.data.currentLevel = returned_data;
    }
);
```

**In CRUD.php, I do:**

```
else if ($functionToRun == "getLevel") {
    $qry = 
        'SELECT levelname 
        FROM userstats
        WHERE id_user_fk ="' . $_SESSION['userid'] . '"';
        $result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $message = $row['levelname'];
    }               
}
echo $message;
```

**What's supposed to happen** *after* **the map is fetched is melonJS loads the map:**

```
game.PlayScreen = me.ScreenObject.extend({

    //Do this on state change
    onResetEvent: function() {
        //load user data with query to database (CRUD.php)
        me.levelDirector.loadLevel(game.data.currentLevel);
```

Why would `game.data.currentLevel` be returning as HTML sometimes, and loading the map other times?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

Okay, I've figured out why it's outputting HTML sometimes... I need to parse it as JSON.

**jQuery:** On doc ready, I just load all user stats and push them into an array. I'm using $.getJSON instead of $.get

```
$.getJSON("php/CRUD.php", {"_functionToRun" : ""},
    function (returned_data) {
        var exp = returned_data.experience,
            levelname = returned_data.levelname,
            player = returned_data.username_fk;

        game.data.dataArray.push(exp, levelname, player);
    }
);
```

**PHP:** Now I just get all columns and echo json_encode($row):

```
else {
    $qry = 
        'SELECT * 
        FROM userstats
        WHERE id_user_fk ="' . $_SESSION['userid'] . '"';

    $result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo json_encode($row);
        exit;
    }   
}
```

**melonJS:** now I pass in the array with the levelname property: game.data.dataArray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbsqL.png)

```
game.PlayScreen = me.ScreenObject.extend({

onResetEvent: function() {
    log(game.data.dataArray[1]);
    me.levelDirector.loadLevel(game.data.dataArray[1]);
```

**When I refresh, log(game.data.dataArray[ 1 ]); outputs "mymap2."**

**When I re-login, I get the following error:**

```
undefined utilities.js:230
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: It sounds more like an issue with session variables or caching as you suggested. Perhaps the first time you're accessing your `CRUD.php`, `$_SESSION['userid']` is empty, so you're getting an error back?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your findings, it looks as though the `$_SESSION['userid']` value may not be set causing the query to fail on the first call. It may also be something else entirely different, the error you posted doesn't appear to be the full message.

**You should be able to use your browsers tools (F12) to see the request made to the `CRUD.php` page, and what the response actually was and thus a more complete error.**

Regardless, you should handle your errors a little nicer, instead of simply using your `die()` call. `die()` not only gives users information they don't need/want but isn't a very good way of catching, logging or handling the errors for debug purposes, as you're finding now.

So instead of:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($qry) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Consider logging an error to your log of choice (generally file) and returning something for the client to parse

```
$result = $mysqli->query($qry);
if($result === FALSE)
{
  // Log error using $mysqli->errno and $mysqli->error
  $message "ERROR"; // Or throw exception, then catch later on
}
else
{
  // Continue on from here. with data retrieval.
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $message = $row['levelname'];
  }
}
```

Then you can check with your JS if `ERROR` is returned, and handle it accordingly.

Comment: After your edit you're not getting a js error, on a line we can't help you with because we can't see all your javascript. Your existing php code will still have the same pitfalls I mentioned above, unless you're handling the potential return of a die() statement instead of JSON.